# How can I analyse a Markov chain whose transition matrix has repeated eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, markov-chains

Consider the following stochastic matrix:
$$M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6}\\
  \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{6}\\
  0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3}
\end{array}\right)$$

It's eigenvectors are $\lambda = 1$, with associated eigenvector $\big(\frac{2}{3} ,1, 1\big)^{\top}$ and $\lambda = \frac{1}{3}$ with associated eigenvector $(0, -1, 1)$ and algebraic multiplicity 2. I have a suspicion that $\lim_{n \to \infty} M^n v = \big(\frac{1}{4} ,\frac{3}{8}, \frac{3}{8}\big)^{\top}$, for any probability vector $v$, but I can't prove this. What I would do in the 2-dimensional case is to use the eigenbasis of $M$ to expand $v$, and note that the components in the direction of eigenvectors, whose corresponding eigenvalues are less than one, decrease to zero in the limit. However, since this stochastic matrix has repeated eigenvalues, this doesn't work.

So I have two questions:

1) Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} M^n v$ converge for any probability vector $v$? If so, what vector does it converge to and why?

2) If the limit always converges, how can I determine the smallest $n$ such that the first component of $M^n (1,0,0)^{\top}$ will be within $\epsilon$ of the first component of the limit, and likewise with the other two components?

Comment: Which eigenvalue is repeated?

Comment: I don't really know much about this topic so I'll just leave a comment. For any stochastic matrix, by Perron-Frobenius, 1 is the largest eigenvalue with multiplicity 1 and the rest are positive. I would think that you could then write $M$ in its Jordan form so that $M = P^{-1}JP$ so that the limit of $M$ is easy to compute. It should then be obvious that $M$ converges to a matrix where every column is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: @Paul As I stated in the details, $\lambda = \frac{1}{3}$ is a repeated eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity 2.

Comment: We do not know what you intend $v$ to be.  If $v$ is a probability vector then $M^nv$ should also be a probability vector (hence it would sum to 1), so $(2/3,1,1)$ would not make sense. The steady state is found by solving the equations $Mv = v$ and $v_1+v_2+v_3=1$, which is a system of 4 equations and 3 unknowns (you can remove one of the three Mv=v equations since it is linearly dependent on the others).

Comment: @11Kilobytes : There are various proofs. One way is through renewal theory: First show the fraction of time being in state $i$ is one-over-mean recurrence time, then show (by irreducible) we eventually get to $i$ regardless of what state we are in. This shows the _time average fraction of time_ converges to a fixed value regardless of initial state.  If you further assume aperiodic, you get that two independent walks eventually meet, which through a cool stochastic coupling argument is used to prove limiting probabilities converge (see, for example, Stochastic Processes by Ross).

Answer (score 2):

**1)**
Firstly, we can consider the $\ell_1$ normalized eigenvector $\mathbf {v}= \begin{bmatrix} 1/4 & 3/8 & 3/8 \end{bmatrix}^T,$ which corresponds to the dominant eigenvalue $\lambda_1 =1.$  The limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} M^n \cdot \mathbf x$ always exists for any probability vector $\mathbf{x}$ and is equal to $\mathbf v.$ Indeed, one way to approach the dominant eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ is through [Power iteration or Power Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration). This method works due to the fact that $\lvert\lambda_1\rvert = 1 > \lvert\lambda_j\rvert,\quad j=2,3.$ Actually, that's the case when the transition matrix is *[irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Reducibility) and [aperiodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Periodicity)*.

What Power iteration states is that we can approach the (normalized) dominant eigenvector starting from almost any vector $\mathbf{x_0}$ through the formula:
$$\mathbf{x}_{k+1}=\frac{M\cdot \mathbf{x}_k}{\| M\cdot \mathbf{x}_k\|}\overset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\mathbf v,$$ considering the $\ell_1$ norm $\|M \cdot \mathbf{x}_k\|_1$. Having described this method, I guess it would be easy enough to answer question **2)**.

Comment: Your "almost" in the second sentence is mysterious but seems not needed.  If the (finite state) Markov chain is irreducible and aperiodic then there is a unique state state probability vector $p$ that solves $Mp=p$, and any other probabiltiy vector $v$ used as an initial condition satisfies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} M^nv = p$.  Using $v=e_i$ (the standard unit vector that is 1 in entry $i$ and 0 else) gives that each column of $M^n$ converges to $p$.  So $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} M^n = [p \: p \:  p \: ... \:  p]$.

Comment: So for a $k$-state discrete time Markov chain that is irreducible and aperiodic, for any vector $x=(x_1, ..., x_k)$ we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} M^n x = (\sum_{i=1}^k x_i)p$.

Comment: Cool, I'll try to prove for my self that any irreducible and aperiodic Markov chain induces a stochastic matrix with an eigenvector w. eigenvalue 1, and that any probability vector must converge to that eigenvector. @Micheal could you show me a resource where I learn more if I fail at proving it?

Comment: @thanasissdr I modified question 2), any hints on how to approach it. The textbook hasn't mentioned Jordan Normal Form yet, so I doubt that that is the approach, however its always good to learn new things.

Comment: @thanasissdr : What is the purpose of your quote?   It is not clear if you are agreeing or disagreeing with my comments above.  My comments argue that you do not need to say "almost any vector x" in this case. Perhaps you mean for general cases when $M$ is not as given in the question, and possibly not corresponding to an ergodic Markov chain. Anyway I felt your "almost" was mysterious.

Comment: @thanasissdr : I am not talking about a sequence $x_k$ from your normalized power method.  I am talking about $M^n x$. You were also talking about $M^n x$ in your second sentence of your answer.